# clock_t returned from clock() is always 0

Tags: c

I am testing the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
int *prefix1(int *,int);
main()
{   
    int i,*X,n,*A;
    srand(time(NULL));
    printf("Dose to n: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    X=(int *)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        X[i]=rand()%100;
    }
    clock_t begin=clock();
    A=prefix1(X,n);
    clock_t end=clock();
    printf("Time taken:%f",(double)(end-begin)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
}
int *prefix1(int *X,int n)
{
    int i,j,s,*A;
    A=(int *)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        s=X[0];
        for(j=1;j<=i;j++)
            s=s+X[j];
        A[i]=s; 
    }
    return A;
}
```

I am trying to calculate how much time `prefix1` takes but the result of

```
(double)(end-begin)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC
```

is always `0`.  I tried `begin` ,`end` inside `prefix1` (at the start and before `return`) and the result is still the same.

Edit:At very low n values the result is 0 but after around 1000+ it gives a result

Comment: To check, just print both `begin` and `end`.

Comment: Both of them are 0.0000

Comment: What value do you give for `n`? Computers run PDQ and don't forget the *granularity* of `clock()`.

Comment: I have tried from 1 to 10000,the result is still 0.0000 both begin and end.Nvm i tried 10000 when i used printf("%f",begin); and printf("%f",end);.With (double)(end-begin)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC) it seems like it works great.Thanks a lot

Comment: On Windows there are 1000 clocks per sec, so 1 tick is 1 millisecond. Modern CPUs are very fast and can do you calculation easily within 1 ms.

Comment: If you are typing in the value for `n` I don't see how `begin` can be `0` because `clock()` returns the count from the start of execution.

Comment: `printf("%f", begin);` ==> `printf("%f", (double)begin);`

Comment: Check your `printf`! Printing a `clock_t` with `%f` gives undefined results.